# Some points are not drawn in line chart using dc.js

Tags: dc.js

In line chart point for(0,0),(0,4)....etc .I mean x value as 0 and y value as 0 or x value as 0 and y value as some other number and vice-verse is not working. How to solve this using dc or d3.js.

I have tried this link  https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/line.html but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: I'm not clear if you think there is a bug, or if you need help getting something to work. Normally using dc.js you will set up your data through crossfilter, as shown in the example you linked. If you just have raw data, D3 might be a better choice, but again I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: It might help explain if you added a running example or at least a screenshot with a sample of the data.